# context menu in rihcfaces tree

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have context menu in rich faces tree component(rich:tree).In my tree i had listed folders and sub folders.By using context menu i can edit datas of the folders and sub folders.I have separate methods for edit folder and sub folders.How can i call this methods in cotnextmenu click action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 different `<a4j:jsFunction>` for both of your edit folders and subfolders action and call them onclick condition in javascript of contextmenu.

```
<rich:menuItem value="Your Context Menu Item" onclick="menuFunction();"></rich:menuItem>
<a4j:jsFunction name="editFolder" action="#{yourFolder.Edit}"/>
<a4j:jsFunction name="editSubFolder" action="#{yourSubFolder.Edit}"/>
```

And script function

```
function menuFunction(){
  if(subFolderNodeValue){    //Here subFolderNodeValue is the value of node, you can set it using nodeSelectionListner
     editSubFolder();
  }else{
     editFolder();
  }
}
```